# Showing $E(X) = \sum_{i}E(X\mid A_i)P(A_i)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Following is my proof.

Suppose $X$ is a discrete-type random variable ranging in the set $S$
and $\{A_i : i=1,2,3,\dots\}$ is a finite or
countably infinite partition of a sample space $\Omega$.

We have
$$P(X=x) = \sum_i{P(X=x\mid A_i)P(A_i)}$$
So
$$xP(X=x) = \sum_i{xP(X=x\mid A_i)P(A_i)}$$
Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(X) &= \sum_{x\in{S}}{xP(X=x)} \\
&= \sum_{x\in{S}}{\sum_i{xP(X=x\mid A_i)P(A_i)}} \\
&= \sum_i{\sum_{x\in{S}}{xP(X=x\mid A_i)P(A_i)}} \\
&= \sum_i{P(A_i)E(X\mid A_i)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Is this right?

Comment: It would be better to specify if $X$ is a discrete-type or continuous-type random variable in your proof, and also put the set of $x$ values that you sum over, rather than just write $\sum_x$.  You would also need to specify if $\{A_i\}$ is a countable set or not, it would be best to write the limits over the $i$ index also.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your advice. I've updated the proof.

Comment: Looks good.  I assume the sets are defined according to an infinite sequence $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\sum_i = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Now I added $A_i$'s definition.